# Validación de un formulario dentro de un Modal con Jquery, Ajax y Php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, modal

Deseo que mi Formulario que se encuentra dentro de mi Modal fuincione, pero no lo eh logrado, no se ejecuta ninguna de las opciones. deseo hacer un login de un administrador de la pagina la cual quiero que se efectué el formulario en el modal, buscando en la base de datos con php para ver si es valido el usuario.
No me funciona pero tampoco en el inspector no me muestra ningún error, ni en el console me muestra el console.log que tengo en mi js.

```html
<button type="button" id="ad"><img id="admi" src="img/admin.png"></button>
```

```js
$(function(){

    $("#fmodal").on("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "php/vale.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                if(parseInt(result)){
                    console.log(result);
                    window.location.href="admi.html"
                }else{
                    console.log(result);
                    alert("Usuario Invalido");
                }

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Es Este mi codigo html del modal.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modaladmin">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #970007;">
                    <font size=2 color="white">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" align="center">Iniciar Sesión</h5>
                    </font>
                </div>
                <form method="POST" id="fmodal">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Por favor, si es Administrador ingrese los siguentes datos:</p>
                    <input type="text" name="adcor" id="adcor" placeholder="Usuario">
                    <input type="password" name="contra" id=contra placeholder="Contraseña">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer" style="background-color: #F4F4F4;" align="center">
                    <button type="submit"  id="mis">Siguiente</button>
                </div>
            </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Es este mi código php para validar mi formulario con la base de datos

```
    <?php
include "conexion.php";
$link=conectarse();

$usuario=$_POST['adcor'];
$contraseña=$_POST['contra'];

$query ="SELECT * FROM Admin WHERE Usuario='$usuario' AND Contraseña='$contraseña'";
$result=mysqli_query($link, $query);
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($num_rows == 1){

        echo 1;
    }else{

        echo 0;
    }

mysqli_close($link); 
 ?>
```

Comment: verifica si esta entrando a tu evento submit

Comment: Saludos @JuanCarlosHdz si ya entra el submit pero el problema ahora es que no esta tomando el varlo de 1 cuando ingreso la contraseña correcta, al contrario me imprime un cero, por lo cual sale el alert de usuario invalido

Comment: El error era que en el button no habia asigando el data-toggle="modal" para que se pudiera ejecutar correctamente el modal y segundo el error que me ayudo @JuanCarlosHdz es que con el mysqli_error($link) me demostro que  tenia un erro de syntaxis por la "ñ" cuando se me habia olvidado que las bd no reconocen esta letra.saludos y gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega una condición en la función `mysqli_query` para controlar los errores por si llega ocurrir alguno, puede que te regrese siempre 0 por un posible error en el query o conexion.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
include "conexion.php";
$link=conectarse();

$usuario=$_POST['adcor'];
$contraseña=$_POST['contra'];

$query ="SELECT * FROM Admin WHERE Usuario='$usuario' AND Contraseña='$contraseña'";
if($result=mysqli_query($link, $query)){
  $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  if($num_rows == 1){
      echo 1;
  }else{
      echo 0;
  }
}
else{
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
}
mysqli_close($link); 
?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias bro te rifaste!!!

Comment: ya me salio hermanito gracias

Comment: @MarioTraz de nada, es un gusto aportar